# c# Treat an array like pointer

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a merge-sort in c# to try and learn the language. I am having trouble splitting the array in the divide step. I come from a c background and would do something like this:

```
void MergeSort(int array[], int size)
{
    if (size == 1) 
        return;
    MergeSort(array, size/2);
    MergeSort(array + size/2, size - size/2);
}
```

My question is, can you do something similar in c#? I am aware there is take and skip methods, but is this the best way?

Comment: Several things - you can use `List<int>` instead of the array (it is a class, so the reference is what gets passed, by value). And though you _can_ use pointers with [unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/chfa2zb8.aspx), that's not really the C# way.

Comment: @oded So in c# is an array a value type?

Comment: My point was more that for resizing it is more appropriate. Arrays are not used as often as other collection types in C#. Arrays are reference types.

Comment: using pointers is possible in c#, but it is one of the more advaned features of the language. if you start learning, you should use the direct addressing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use indexes instead of pointers.

```
void MergeSort(int[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex){
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could pass the index you want to use to the function:

```
private static void MergeSort(int[] array, int size, int index) {
    if (size == 1) {
        return;
    }
    MergeSort(array, size / 2, index);
    MergeSort(array, size - size / 2, index + size / 2);
}
```